# Finding a projective resolution for a direct sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory, modules, homological-algebra

How can I find a projective resolution of the $k[x]$-module $k[x]\oplus \frac{k[x]}{(x^m)}$ (where $k$ is a field and $m\in\mathbb{Z}$)? That is, I want to find a long exact sequence $$\cdots\rightarrow P_{n+1}\rightarrow P_n\rightarrow\cdots\rightarrow P_0\rightarrow k[x]\oplus \frac{k[x]}{(x^m)}\rightarrow 0$$ where $P_i$ are all projective $k[x]$-modules. This is part of a larger exercise, but I can't get started without the projective resolution.

**Edit:** For my purposes, I would also be happy with a **free** resolution of $$k[x]\oplus \frac{k[x]}{(x^m)}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Take the direct sum of projective resolutions of each summand. The first summand is free, so its projective resolution is rather simple. The second summand is the cokernel of multiplication by $x^m$ in $k[x]$. So you get a finite free resolution of length $1$ (which is normal since a P.I.D. has global dimension $1$).

Comment: What you're saying is, the resolution for the second summand should be $k[x]\rightarrow k[x]\rightarrow k[x]/(x^m)\rightarrow 0$ (where the first map is $\cdot x^m$) and the resolution of the first summand is $k[x]\rightarrow k[x]\rightarrow 0$? The resolution that I'm after is the sum of the two component-wise? i.e. $k[x]\oplus k[x]\rightarrow k[x]\oplus \frac{k[x]}{(x^m)}\rightarrow 0$

Comment: @user4355 If you add some more arrows then yes, that's what he meant.

Comment: I confirm, taking into account multiplication by $x^m$ is injective.

Comment: @user26857 How many more arrows do I need to add? Is it not just a $0\rightarrow$ on the left?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly that.